# RecyclerView.OnScrollListener not called when single item is moved using ItemTouchHelper

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onscrolllistener

I have the following bug that's already reported [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=210148), and the report is as follows:

Library used
com.android.support:appcompat-v7
com.android.support:recyclerview-v7

Version used: 23.4.0
Theme used: Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar
Devices/Android versions reproduced on: Nexus 6P Android 6.0.1

- Relevant code to trigger the issue: https://github.com/AOrobator/RecyclerViewBugDemo
- A screenrecord or screenshots showing the issue (if UI related) https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-yFkNiHynDBSU9mQS1TcmFOWjQ/view?usp=sharing

When swapping a single item using ItemTouchHelper and ItemTouchHelper.Callback, the RecyclerView is scrolled, yet the RecyclerView.OnScrollListener is not called.

---

I'm pretty sure this is a bug, but was wondering if there any known work-arounds.

Comment: If anyone wanna know, `LinearLayoutManager.scrollHorizontallyBy` can be used to intercept the direction of the scroll. Using that inside `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener.onScrollStateChanged` helps detecting which direction the user is swiping, even though there's one single item in the list.